# Virtualenv activating and deactivating on windows

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

I have been able to create a virtual environment on a Windows machine by following the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html). I am very familiar with `virtualenv` but on macos.

However when I try to activate the environment:

`Scripts/activate.bat` as described in the docs

I see no action that shows it has been activated. I do see time pass before the bash resets ready for another command so thats something.

But when I type `deactivate` to deactivate the virtual environment I get

`bash: deactivate: command not found`

So either it is being activated and I am not correctly deactivating (even though the docs says just to type `deactivate` much like mac).

Or nothing is being activated.

Anyone familiar?

Comment: Please stop rolling back improvements to the question. You're not helping anyone, including yourself, by doing so.

Answer (score 2):

The `.bat` files are for the Windows command shell, `cmd.exe`. If you're using bash on Windows, you should use the corresponding (ba)sh scripts, for example `source tutorial-env/bin/activate`.

Comment: so i tried that with no success and when I open up in a bash I still see the Scripts folder I do not see a bin folder. What your saying is that I am only able to activate and deactivate the environment via cmd.exe not powershell and not gitbash. But then I am not able to use pip inside of cmd.exe isn't that true?